# How to get data from one class to another class in grid view through query string in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, webforms

Hello friends i am new on asp.net c#. I was practicing Grid View and editing and updating data within Grid View. Now i want to Edit Data through insert table (Notification.aspx.cs) by using Query string andget it from grid view (GridView.aspx.cs). So tell me what to do. Code is following:
GridView_.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Task_DB.Classes;

namespace Task_DB
{
    public partial class GridView_ : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        SqlConnection con;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();


        public void BindData()
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from [Notifications_]";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                BindData();
            }
        }
        protected void Submit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                //con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                //cmd.CommandText = "insert into [Notifications_](user_name,News_Day,News_date,News_title,News_Link,News_Upload,News_Desc) values(@1,@2,@3,@5,@6,@7)";
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", Name.Text);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", NewsDay.Text);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", NewsDate.Text);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", NewsTitle.Text);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@5", NewsLink.Text);
                ////cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@6", FileUpload1.FileName.Trim());
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@7", NewsDesc.Text);

                //if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                //{
                //    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + FileUpload1.FileName);
                //}
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@6", FileUpload1.FileName);
                //int j = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                ////Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");


        }
        protected void Reset_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            BindData();
        }
        protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            BindData();
        }
        protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            Label lbldeleteID = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Id");
            cmd.CommandText = "Delete from [Notifications_] where ID='" + lbldeleteID.Text + "'";
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            BindData();
        }
        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            BindData();
        }
        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            Label id = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Id");
            TextBox name = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Name");
            TextBox day = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Day");
            TextBox date = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Date");
            TextBox title = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Title");
            TextBox link = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Link");
            FileUpload upload = (FileUpload)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Upload");
            TextBox desc = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Desc");



            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "Update [Notifications_] set News_Day = @NewsDay, News_date = @NewsDate, News_title = @NewsTitle, News_Link = @NewsLink, News_Upload= @NewsUpload, News_Desc= @NewsDesc where ID = @Id";
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewsDay", day.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewsDate", date.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewsTitle", title.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewsLink", link.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewsUpload", upload.FileName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewsDesc", desc.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id.Text);

            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            BindData();
            con.Close();
        }
        protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            BindData();
        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Notification.aspx.cs

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Task_DB.Classes;

namespace Task_DB
{
    public partial class Notification : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["username"] != null)
            {
                String username = Session["username"].ToString();
                name.InnerText = Session["username"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
            }
        }


        //protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //{
        //      this.NewsDay.Text = this.Calendar1.SelectedDate.Value.DayOfWeek.ToString();
        //      this.NewsDate.Text = this.Calendar1.SelectedDate.Value.Date.ToString("DD MMMM");
        //}


        protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String User = this.name.InnerText.Trim();
            String Day = this.NewsDay.Text.Trim();
            String Date = this.NewsDate.Text.Trim();
            String Title = this.NewsTitle.Text.Trim();
            String Link = this.NewsLink.Text.Trim();
            String Upload = this.FileUpload1.FileName.Trim();
            String Desc = this.NewsDesc.Text.Trim();
            String Status = this.NewsStatus.Text.Trim();
            String file_path = "/Images/";
            InformationPanel info_obj = new InformationPanel();

            String result = info_obj.insert_info(User, Day, Date, Title, Link, Upload, Desc, Status);
            this.result_to_show.InnerText = result;

            if (FileUpload1.HasFile && result == "Success")
            {
                string fileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(file_path) + fileName);
                this.Form.Disabled = true;
                Response.Redirect("Notification.aspx");
            }
            else {
                this.Form.Disabled = false; 
            }


        }
    }


}
```

Comment: you can do it with session or a new query string

Comment: i need a hint or example to get it

Comment: jackjop just gave you a hint. We're not here to code your website for you. That's up to you. You need to do a little research.

Answer (score 0):

```html
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("NewsTitle");
                Label lbl1 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Id");
                lbl.Text = "<a href='Notification.aspx'?Id=" + lbl1.Text + "&NewsTitle=" + lbl1.Text + ">"+lbl.Text+"</a>";
            }
        }
```